# Fetch data in to respective edittexts from MySQL database in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

My app has an An Activity which retrieves the data from MySQL in to edit texts on clicking a button

1) Activity code, php code and layout code is being attached .

There is no error in the compile time and there is some error in the log-cat .. The dialog opens up , keep running for seconds and then dismisses but the edit text fields are not filled up by the data from MySQL.

2) The name of the table in the MySQL is services_provider_details 1 which contains respective columns (   Service_Provider_ID,Name,Address, Pin-code, Phone_Number,DOB,Adhara_Number,Price,Specialization,Status ) .

"Here is my code:".

```
public class Update extends  Activity {


EditText  et_spid,et_fullname,et_address,et_sid,et_aadhar,et_dob,et_phone,et_pincode,et_price,et_status,et_spl ;
Spinner spinner;
Button update_button, go;
String spid;

InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null ;
String myJSON;
JSONArray peoples = null;



    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    public static  final String TAG_PROVIDERS = "providers";
    public static  final String TAG_SPID = "spid";
    public static  final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static  final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static  final String TAG_PINCODE = "Pincode";
    public static final  String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "Phone_Number";
    public static  final String TAG_AADHARNUMBER = "Aadhar_Number";
    public static  final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    public static  final String TAG_SPL = "spl";
    public static  final String TAG_STATUS = "status";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update);
          et_spid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_spid_insert);
          et_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name_insert);
          et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_address_insert);
          et_pincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_pin_insert);
          et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_phone_insert);
          et_aadhar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_aadhar_insert);
          spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        et_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_price);
        et_status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_status);
        et_spl =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_speacialisation); 
         update_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);
         go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_go);



        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                spid=et_spid.getText().toString();
                new go().execute();
            }
        });
        }

    class go extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog progress;
        String Url="http://192.168.2.7/myapp/update.php";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String res = "";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Update.this, "Loading Details",
                    "Please wait..", false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("spid",spid));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    
         try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     


        return res;

     }
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            myJSON = response ;
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);


             String Name=(c.getString("Name"));
                String Address=(c.getString("Address"));
                String Pincode=(c.getString("Pincode"));
                String Phone_Number=(c.getString("Phone_Number"));
                String Aadhar_Number=(c.getString("Aadhar_Number"));
                String price=(c.getString("price"));
                String spl=(c.getString("spl"));
                String status=(c.getString("status"));


                et_fullname.setText(Name);
                 et_address.setText(Address);
                 et_pincode.setText(Pincode);
                 et_phone.setText(Phone_Number);
                 et_aadhar.setText(Aadhar_Number); 
                 et_price.setText(price);
                et_spl.setText(spl);
                et_status.setText(status);




            } 
            }
             catch(Exception e)
            {

                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
progress.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

3. PHP code

```css
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
mysql_select_db("myapp");  



     $spid = $_POST['spid'];


    $sql="select * from services_provider_details1 WHERE Service_Provider_ID='$spid' " ;
    $r=mysql_query($sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        array_push($result,
array('Name'=>$row[1],'Address'=>$row[2],'Pincode'=>$row[3],'Phone_Number'=>$row[4],'Aadhar_Number'=>$row[6],'price'=>$row[8],'spl'=>$row[9],'status'=>$row[10]));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysql_close();

?>
```

Logcat of the programme when run

```css
04-10 13:24:57.105: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.145: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.145: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.225: W/System.err(1859): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-10 13:24:57.296: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
04-10 13:24:57.296: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
04-10 13:24:57.306: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
04-10 13:24:57.325: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
04-10 13:24:57.325: W/System.err(1859):     at com.example.homerun.Update$go.onPostExecute(Update.java:197)
04-10 13:24:57.345: W/System.err(1859):     at com.example.homerun.Update$go.onPostExecute(Update.java:1)
04-10 13:24:57.357: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-10 13:24:57.376: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-10 13:24:57.376: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-10 13:24:57.396: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 13:24:57.396: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 13:24:57.406: W/System.err(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-10 13:24:57.426: W/System.err(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 13:24:57.436: W/System.err(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 13:24:57.436: W/System.err(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 13:24:57.465: W/System.err(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 13:24:57.465: W/System.err(1859):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 13:24:57.475: I/Choreographer(1859): Skipped 113 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 13:24:58.285: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:58.285: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

And Please also tell me that Is XML File required?

Comment: you are not getting an empty response from server. Use tools like [POSTMAN](http://getpostman.com) to check the server responses

Comment: @SachinThampan When I tried to run my php file it works fine , and when i Put some value of SPID to check manually then it returns the value related to that SPID which is required by me when this php file is made to run on server . 
    ' 
   Notice: Undefined index: spid in C:\xampp\htdocs\homerun\select.php on line 7
{"result":[{"Name":"","Address":"","Pincode":"0","Phone_Number":"","Aadhar_Number":"","price":"0","spl":"","status":"0"}]}'

Comment: you are running on android emulator or a real device?

Comment: @SachinThampan On emulator

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost doesn't return any data. Change your php code and http request from android to use GET instead of POST

You are not "posting" anything anyways. Http GET is the right thing to use.

Comment: here is what i got on running the app in debug mode . 
     `myJSON "" (id=830013406208) 
 count 0 
 hashCode 0 
 offset 0 
 value  (id=830013406240) 
peoples null 
result "{"result":[{"Name":"ABC","Address":"XYZ","Pincode":"123456","Phone_Number":"9999999999","Aadhar_Number":"126526527","price":"0","spl":"","status":"0"}]}\n" (id=830017559384) 
 count 213 
 hashCode 0 
 offset 0 
 value  (id=830017381304) 

`